# Unmet dependancies have kept me from upgrading since 14.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

All my PHP PPAs are disabled because they are Trusty PPAs.  Have been following the help in other related SE questions, but ran into a roadblock.

```
kikjezrous@ubuntu-lenovo:~$ sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 42
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 42
Investigating (0) xserver-xorg-core [ amd64 ] < 2:1.16.0-1ubuntu1.3 -> 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu3.1 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-core:amd64 Conflicts on xserver-xorg-video-modesetting [ amd64 ] < 0.9.0-1build1 > ( x11 )
  Considering xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64 -3 as a solution to xserver-xorg-core:amd64 55
  Added xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing xserver-xorg-core:amd64 via remove of xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64
Investigating (0) libwinpr-crt0.1 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libwinpr-crt0.1:amd64 Breaks on libfreerdp1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1)
  Considering libfreerdp1:amd64 -30 as a solution to libwinpr-crt0.1:amd64 34
  Added libfreerdp1:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libwinpr-crt0.1:amd64 via remove of libfreerdp1:amd64
Investigating (0) libical1a [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0-1.3 > ( libs )
Broken libical1a:amd64 Breaks on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-1 > ( libs )
  Considering libical1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libical1a:amd64 13
  Added libical1:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libical1a:amd64 via remove of libical1:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-common [ amd64 ] < 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 -> 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 > ( database )
Broken mysql-common:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-server-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 > ( database )
  Considering mysql-server-5.5:amd64 -4 as a solution to mysql-common:amd64 8
  Added mysql-server-5.5:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing mysql-common:amd64 via remove of mysql-server-5.5:amd64
Investigating (0) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 3
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
Investigating (0) libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( httpd )
Broken libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 3 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 1
  Removing libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (0) kactivities [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.9.0-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken kactivities:amd64 Conflicts on libkactivities-bin [ amd64 ] < 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu2 > ( kde )
  Considering libkactivities-bin:amd64 -3 as a solution to kactivities:amd64 1
  Added libkactivities-bin:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing kactivities:amd64 via remove of libkactivities-bin:amd64
Investigating (0) libmetacity-private2 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:3.14.3-1ubuntu7 > ( libs )
Broken libmetacity-private2:amd64 Breaks on libmetacity-private1 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.12.0-1ubuntu4 > ( libs )
  Considering libmetacity-private1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libmetacity-private2:amd64 1
  Added libmetacity-private1:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libmetacity-private2:amd64 via remove of libmetacity-private1:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-server-core-5.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 > ( database )
Broken mysql-server-core-5.6:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-server-core-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 > ( database )
  Considering mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64 -2 as a solution to mysql-server-core-5.6:amd64 0
  Added mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing mysql-server-core-5.6:amd64 via remove of mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-server-5.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 > ( database )
Broken mysql-server-5.6:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-client-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 > ( database )
  Considering mysql-client-5.5:amd64 -4 as a solution to mysql-server-5.6:amd64 0
  Added mysql-client-5.5:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing mysql-server-5.6:amd64 via remove of mysql-client-5.5:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-client-core-5.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 > ( database )
Broken mysql-client-core-5.6:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-client-core-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 > ( database )
  Considering mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 -2 as a solution to mysql-client-core-5.6:amd64 0
  Added mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing mysql-client-core-5.6:amd64 via remove of mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64
Investigating (0) php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( httpd ) (>= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) (>= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
  Try Installing libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) before changing php5:amd64
Investigating (0) libmarblewidget19 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libmarblewidget19:amd64 Depends on libastro1 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu2 -> 4:14.12.3-0ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (= 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu2)
  Considering libastro1:amd64 4 as a solution to libmarblewidget19:amd64 -1
  Removing libmarblewidget19:amd64 rather than change libastro1:amd64
Investigating (0) totem-mozilla [ amd64 ] < 3.10.1-1ubuntu6 > ( video )
Broken totem-mozilla:amd64 Depends on totem [ amd64 ] < 3.10.1-1ubuntu6 -> 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.10.1-1ubuntu6)
  Considering totem:amd64 3 as a solution to totem-mozilla:amd64 -2
  Removing totem-mozilla:amd64 rather than change totem:amd64
Investigating (0) libkgeomap1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0~digikam4.2.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libkgeomap1:amd64 Depends on libmarblewidget19 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 4:4.13.90)
  Considering libmarblewidget19:amd64 -1 as a solution to libkgeomap1:amd64 -2
  Removing libkgeomap1:amd64 rather than change libmarblewidget19:amd64
Investigating (1) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 3
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (1) php5:amd64
Re-Instated php5:amd64 (2 vs 2)
Investigating (1) libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd )
Broken libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 3 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1
  Holding Back libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (2) php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-cli:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 3 as a solution to php5-cli:amd64 4
  Added php5-json:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing php5-cli:amd64 via keep of php5-json:amd64
Investigating (2) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 4
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
Investigating (2) php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( httpd ) (>= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) (>= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
  Try Installing libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) before changing php5:amd64
Investigating (3) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 10
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
Investigating (3) libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd )
Broken libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1
  Holding Back libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (4) php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-cli:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-cli:amd64 4
  Removing php5-cli:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (4) php5-readline [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-readline:amd64 Depends on php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php ) (= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4)
  Considering php5-cli:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-readline:amd64 3
  Removing php5-readline:amd64 rather than change php5-cli:amd64
Investigating (4) php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( httpd ) (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
  Try Installing libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) before changing php5:amd64
Investigating (5) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 10
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
Investigating (5) libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd )
Broken libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1
  Holding Back libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (6) php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-cli:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-cli:amd64 10
  Removing php5-cli:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (6) php5-readline [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-readline:amd64 Depends on php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php ) (= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4)
  Considering php5-cli:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-readline:amd64 10
  Removing php5-readline:amd64 rather than change php5-cli:amd64
Investigating (6) php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( httpd ) (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
  Try Installing libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) before changing php5:amd64
Investigating (7) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 10
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
Investigating (7) libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd )
Broken libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1
  Holding Back libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (8) php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-cli:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-cli:amd64 10
  Removing php5-cli:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Investigating (8) php5-readline [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5-readline:amd64 Depends on php5-cli [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php ) (= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4)
  Considering php5-cli:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-readline:amd64 10
  Removing php5-readline:amd64 rather than change php5-cli:amd64
Investigating (8) php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( php )
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( httpd ) (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
Broken php5:amd64 Depends on libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~)
  Considering libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1 as a solution to php5:amd64 0
  Try Installing libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd ) before changing php5:amd64
Investigating (9) php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
Broken php5-json:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20121212 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering php5-common:amd64 10 as a solution to php5-json:amd64 10
  Removing php5-json:amd64 rather than change phpapi-20121212:amd64
Investigating (9) libapache2-mod-php5filter [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 > ( universe/httpd )
Broken libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 Depends on php5-json [ amd64 ] < 1.3.6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 > ( php )
  Considering php5-json:amd64 10 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 -1
  Holding Back libapache2-mod-php5filter:amd64 rather than change php5-json:amd64
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1~) but it is not going to be installed
 php5-cli : Depends: php5-json but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

The guide I was following said to work on each package individually.  This seems like major overkill.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using aptitude's resolver, which lets you choose which way of resolving the package conflicts.